# plotting percentages upon a country's region in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, visualization, r-sf

I have collected some data on a Survey in which I asked from what Brazil's region the participants were. I have Brazil's map and its states with `ne_states` but I'm struggling with **ploting the percentages upon the map according to the region**.

- Getting the map:

Note:
Brazil has 26 states + the Federal District 
Brazil has 5 regions ('Sul', 'Sudeste', 'Centro-Oeste', 'Norte', 'Nordeste')

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthhires)
library(stringr)

### filter Brazil: 

BRA <- ne_states(country = "Brazil", returnclass = "sf") 

### group states according to region:

regionsBR <- BRA %>%
  mutate(postal = factor(postal),
         Q8 = fct_collapse(postal, 
                               'Sul' = c('RS', 'SC', 'PR'),
                               'Sudeste' = c('RJ', 'SP', 'MG', 'ES'),
                               'Centro-Oeste' = c('MS', 'MT', 'GO', 'DF'),
                               'Norte' = c('RO', 'AC', 'AM', 'RR', 'PA', 'TO', 'AP'),
                               'Nordeste' = c('BA', 'PI', 'MA', 'CE', 'SE', 'AL', 'PE', 'PB', 'RN'))) %>% 
  select(Q8)
```

- the data from the survey is:

```
### Question 8:

regionsQuest 
            Q8  n  prop   sd
1        Norte  4  8.51 0.11
2     Nordeste  5 10.64 0.11
3      Sudeste  8 17.02 0.11
4 Centro-Oeste 14 29.79 0.11
5          Sul 16 34.04 0.11
```

- I tried to join them by `Q8` in order to plot the percentages on the map but it didn't work since in `regionsBR` I get 27 different coordenates to be ploted while in `regionsQuest` I only have the 5 regions in `Q8`
- the `ggplot2` code is:

```
### join data ### 

regionsJoined <- regionsQuest %>% full_join(regionsBR)

### PLOT MAP WITH GGPLOT 2:

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = BRA, fill = "#D3D3D3") + # plot Brazil's map behind it
  geom_sf(data = regionsBR, color = "black",  aes(fill = Q8)) + # color of the map's border (color); color inside of it (fill)
  theme_light() +
  geom_text(data = regionsJoined, 
            aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)} %'),
                  x = prop,
                y = prop)) +
          ##  nudge_y = 3, nudge_x = 0.05,size = 5) +
```

- which leaves me with:

[image: plot]

- **Question** : How can I plot the percentages upon each region on the map? Thanks in adv.
- data `Q8`:

```
dput(regionsQuest)
structure(list(Q8 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Norte", "Nordeste", 
"Sudeste", "Centro-Oeste", "Sul"), class = "factor"), n = c(4L, 
5L, 8L, 14L, 16L), prop = c(8.51, 10.64, 17.02, 29.79, 34.04), 
    sd = c(0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `geom_sf_text` instead of `geom_text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited version changing from {rnaturalearth} packages to {geobr} package (the former didn't worked here)

EDIT: As Allan Cameron [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580103/plotting-percentages-upon-a-countrys-region-in-ggplot2/75587345#comment133343326_75580103), you need to change from `geom_text` to `geom_sf_text`

```r
# packages ----------------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
library(geobr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

# data --------------------------------------------------------------------

states <- geobr::read_state()
#> Using year 2010

region <- geobr::read_region() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(name_region = ifelse(name_region == "Centro Oeste", "Centro-Oeste", name_region))
#> Using year 2010

regionsQuest <- structure(list(Q8 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Norte", "Nordeste", 
                                              "Sudeste", "Centro-Oeste", "Sul"), class = "factor"), n = c(4L, 
                                                                                                          5L, 8L, 14L, 16L), prop = c(8.51, 10.64, 17.02, 29.79, 34.04), 
               sd = c(0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                    -5L), class = "data.frame")

new_dataset <- regionsQuest %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(region, by = c("Q8" = "name_region"))

# plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

new_dataset %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Q8,
              geometry = geom))+
  geom_sf(data = states,
          color = "black",
          fill = NA)+
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = str_glue('{round(prop, 1.5)} %'),
                   geometry = geom))+
  theme_light()
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about this ```geobr``` , good to know! then I don't have to extract the regions manually. Thanks! Should we be concerned about the warning?

Comment: No, it'll be only important if you use it for distance calculations